# Web App for containers (linux) - Container settings - Missing ACR image tags

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I currently have a Linux app service (Web app) running a docker container, the containers are pushed to the ACR on build, with tags currently being the commit hash (shortened to the first 6 characters).

Continuous deployment has not been setup currently for various reasons.

In the "Container settings" window of the portal I've noticed that a large number of tags are missing - preventing the selection of some the latest built images.

All of the tags are currently available in the registry, however it seems that only ~100 tags are available in the drop down of the portal - which are listed in a alpha-numeric sorted list.

The web app is running without issue, however the tags are missing which is making selecting and deploying the containers directly from the portal an issue.

It appears that the Azure function which is returning the list of tags is causing the issue, as mentioned above only returning a partial number of the actual available tags.

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with more than a hundred images stored in the ACR. But as far as I know, there no limitation about the tags of the ACR images. You can see the [Image Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-storage#image-limits) here. Also the [App Service Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

Comment: I get that there are no limits based on those links, but they're not the actual problem.

The problem lies within the portal UI:

App Service -> Container Settings -> Azure Container Registry -> Tag

It's that the tags in this list aren't showing the entire set of available tags.

Comment: OK, I know what you want and I will keep resolve it. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Dan I have confirmed that it is a bug and it is being fixed. I will update the answer if the bug has fixed.

Comment: @Dan Any more question?

Comment: Also following, as this is an issue for us.  Is there a powershell az command to use in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, the issue seems just happen in the portal.

Comment: @Dan The issue has fixed now. You can use it in the portal.